# How to redirect to jira dashboard from servlet

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to redirect from servlet to jira's dashboard.

What i am trying to do : when the user click create isse and fill all the details and submit, i check if the user with openid, after i check, i need to redirect the user to dashboard or i should be above to redirect to any workflow screen.

I tried the redirect with the following lines.

response.sendRedirect("/Dashboard.jspa");

after the servlet finishes, i want to redirect, i have the HttpServletResponse object. when i use the above redirect method it doesn't redirect.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with sendRedirect when doing some Confluence development. I opted for a JavaScript solution, although it's probably not what you were hoping for.

Call your servlet using an AJAX request with the required data (onclick of create issue in  your case I guess), then if a success status code is received, use `window.location.href = "/Dashboard.jspa";` to perform the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the following code:

```java
String redirectUrl = request.getContextPath() + "/";
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

In this case, the user will be redirected to the default "home" page in Jira (this will not necessarily be Dashboard.jsp, but with default settings it does).

I've tested this code on Jira 7.3.1